# Is Spring CollectionUtils a public api?

Tags: java, spring

I am curious to know if developers are discouraged from using the org.springframework.util package. Is it considered a "private" portion of the API? The Javadoc for CollectionUtils, for example, says the following: "Mainly for internal use within the framework; consider Jakarta's Commons Lang for a more comprehensive suite of String utilities."